# Error in gradle sync(Android Studio)

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I was trying to follow the instructions from Google developers in setting up Google play services:
https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

And in the step 2, I copied this:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
...

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
}
```

in the gradle file, then I realized that that piece of code was already there, with the exception of the last line(...sevices:6.1.+'), I copied the `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'` and placed where it belongs,now my gradle looks like:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'theapp.application.developer.moreappinfo.seconpart'
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 3
        versionName '1.2'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
}
```

went to sync with gradle files and this error appears an I don't know how to fix it:

Error:

```
Failed to find: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0
    Error:Open in Project Structure dialog
    Open File
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the "Android Support Repository" in your SDK Manager.

1. Open your Android SDK Manager
2. Scroll down to the "extras" folder, and check the box next to "Android Support Repository"
3. Click "Install packages..." and accept all of the licenses that it asks you to accept.